# Populate dynamically created html elements inside of a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, template-literals

I created a block of html elements inside of a for loop that lists a starting address, destination address, distance and time between each address. I have an array of addresses named `address`that I am trying to push to my `startaddress` element in the html. Inside of the for loop, the id for `startaddress` is incremented dynamically with a template literal `${[i]}` in order to create new elements based on the length of the `address` array. Inside of the for loop, I created variable as template strings, I think that's the correct terminology, but they don't seem to be recognized as variables in the console. If I console.log them, I get an error message

> startInput is not defined

> destInput is not defined

Obviously what I'm doing is wrong, but I'm not sure how to populate `startaddress` dynamically. What I'm ultimately hoping to do inside of the for loop is create startInput1, startinput2, etc. along with that same sequence for destInput1, destInput2, etc. How can I go creating these dynamic variables inside of the for loop. Thanks in advance and here is my code:

```
                    let container = document.querySelector(".container-lg")

                    for (let i = 0; i <= addresses.length; i++) {
                        let div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.classList.add("card", "card-body", "mb-3");
                        console.log(addresses[i]);
                        div.innerHTML = `<div class="mx-auto" style="width: 500px; margin-top:50px;">

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Starting Address</span>
                                </div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start Address" id="startaddress${i}">
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Destination Address</span>
                                </div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Destination Address" id="destAddress${i}">
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Distance <span id="distance"></span></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Trip Time <span id="time1"></span></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                        container.appendChild(div);
                        let startInput = document.querySelector(`#startaddress${[i]}`);
                        startInput.value = addresses[i];
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out why I couldn't dynamically update each element after creating inside of the for loop. Of course, with Gustavo's help. I added the div variable, classList.add and the container.appendChild inside of the for loop and that solved the problem. I was getting null for startaddresses because of trying to assign the variable and its value before it was being added to the DOM. I updated my code in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

`let startInput${[i]} = document.querySelector("#startaddress${[i]}")`; why is this part using template literals? also even using plain javascript this assignment would not work, (you cannot dynamically add numbers to a constant) but also in your case you would not need to, since doing:

```
let startInput = document.querySelector(`#startaddress${i}`)
```

will assign a new value to the variable on every loop
also when on html template, assign the id this way:

```
id=`startaddress${i}`
```

Comment: Gustavo, I tried using let startInput = document.querySelector("#startaddress${[i]}") to replace the original startInput${[i]} variable but I'm getting this error message: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#startaddress${[i]}' is not a valid selector.
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: adjusted my response you have to use template literals inside query selector

Comment: That seems to get rid of the error and allows me to create the variable, but if I try and populate each element with startInput.value = `addresses${[i]}`; I get an error message of : index.html:143 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: also forgot about how you were passing the template string on html, edited the response again